# non-malleable commitment and security parameters

Tags: cr.crypto-security, concurrency

Although it is not clear, it appears that definition 5 of [this paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/huijia/papers/concnmc-owf.pdf),

page 10 of [this paper](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~alon/PAPERS/conc-nmc/conc-nmc.ps), and page 6 of [this paper](http://aeolus.ceid.upatras.gr/scientific-reports/2nd_year_reports/OPV07.pdf), each assume

that the honest parties will all use the *same* security parameter.

> Are there any known constructions of concurrent non-malleable
>   
> commitment that do not assume a common security parameter?

(If I'm wrong about the first sentence in this post, then

one of those three papers might be such a construction.)

I notice that, by rounding to a value of the form $2^\left(2^n\right)\hspace{-0.02 in}$,$\:$ one can assume without

loss of generality that at most $\:O\hspace{.01 in}(1)\:$ different security parameters will be used.

Comment: I've never seen a paper that considered the case of non-matching security parameters for any primitive.  Is this motivated by anything in particular?

Comment: It's just motivated by me noticing that this would be needed in order to avoid being $\hspace{.61 in}$ "locked in" to a particular security parameter as computational abilities increase. $\;\;\;$